# Deploy DotNet application

Tags: .net, deployment

I created a dotnet application and I compiled it with Dotnet v4.5
I want to create a setup for my application to install it in others computers.
Should the other Computer have DN v4.5 installed (precisely) ? or higher versions will work ? 
PS: I tried to run my application in a computer, It shows that Dn v4.5 is not installed but when I tried to install v4.5 it didn't work because higher version was installed (v4.7).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with offline installer

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2858728/the--net-framework-4-5-1-offline-installer-and--net-framework-4-5-1-la

Comment: What I want is to configure my application to run with the available version of dotNet in the computer because in my case I compiled the application with v4.5 but it didn't run in a pc with v4.7 installed !